# Database Cleaner not working in minitest rails

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3.2, database-cleaner

My Minitest controller tests are working fine if I run them alone using `rake minitest:controllers` but when I run `rake minitest:all` then I get validation failed error. It is because email is already used in model tests. I used DatabaseCleaner to clean the database but unable to clean database.

My code for database cleaner:

```
require "database_cleaner"
DatabaseCleaner.strategy = :transaction

class MiniTest::Rails::ActionController::TestCase
    include Devise::TestHelpers

    def setup
      DatabaseCleaner.start
    end

    def teardown
      DatabaseCleaner.clean
    end
```

Answer (score 15, accepted):

**Short answer:**

```
gem install "minitest-around"
```

**Long answer:**

before/after or setup/teardown in minitest are **NOT** hooks as in rspec, therefore you can't have multiple before/after or setup/teardown in minitest, since what they do is just redefining the method.

To solve this issue, you can use `minitest-around`, which adds support for multiple `before`/`after` or `setup`/`teardown` and `around`, simply add the gem to your test group:

```
# put in your Gemfile
gem 'minitest-around', group: :test
```

For setting up the database_cleaner, you can have it as you want, following is an example of the setup:

```
# tests/support/database_cleaner.rb
DatabaseCleaner.strategy = :transaction
DatabaseCleaner.clean_with(:truncation)

class Minitest::Rails::ActionController::TestCase
  def setup
    DatabaseCleaner.start
  end

  def teardown
    DatabaseCleaner.clean
  end
end
```

And in your test files:

```
# tests/your/test/file_test.rb
require 'support/database_cleaner'

# assertions here ...
```

That's it, see the [Github](https://github.com/splattael/minitest-around) for detailed info.

Comment: Note that you CAN have multiple 'setups' through calling `super` in the child test's `setup` method.

Answer (score 5):

If for whatever reason you don't want to add the 'minitest-around' gem (to have more than one setup and teardown method), you can do this in your `test_helper.rb`...

```
require "database_cleaner"
DatabaseCleaner.strategy = :transaction

module AroundEachTest
  def before_setup
    super
    DatabaseCleaner.start
  end

  def after_teardown
    super
    DatabaseCleaner.clean
  end
end

class Minitest::Test
  include AroundEachTest
end
```

Comment: This was simple enough without having to add an extra gem

Answer (score 4):

I found my mistake ,may be it helps someone else ..

I should write DatabaseCleaner.start in setup of every model test where setup is defined, as i am overwriting setup method in every test file.

Comment: You can add [minitest-around](https://github.com/splattael/minitest-around) to add multiple before/after.

Comment: @HendraUzia can you add example code and answer it.

Comment: Don't do that, use a subclass & call `super` before any setup you need - see my answer for an illustration.

Answer (score 2):

This is why I like Minitest; no fancy DSL to block thinking about how to use Ruby properly.

My setup is as follows:

In `test_helper.rb`

```rb
class MyTest < Minitest::Test
  def setup
    DatabaseCleaner.start
  end

  def teardown
    DatabaseCleaner.clean
  end
end
```

Then I just subclass this in any test that need database cleaning. Note the call `super` first cleans the db before any subclass-specific setup. The same call to `super` would need to be included in any subclass `teardown` method, but this can usually be omitted entirely.

```rb
class FooTest < MyTest
  def setup
    super
    @foo = Foo.new(bar: 'whatever')
  end

  def test_save
    @foo.save
    assert_equal 1, Foo.count
  end
end
```

If I need to subclass `MyTest` further (e.g. for integration tests) I include its own `setup` & `teardown` methods with calls to `super` so it goes right up the inheritance tree.

Answer (score 0):

You can DRY up that repetition with this

```
DatabaseCleaner.strategy = :truncation
class MiniTest::Spec
  before :each do
    DatabaseCleaner.clean
  end
end
```

This example subclasses the spec runner, but you can pick your test environment of choice.